# on the interval $[-1,1]$, $\sum (-1)^n {x^2+n^2\over n^3}$ is absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

on the interval $[-1,1]$, $\sum (-1)^n {x^2+n^2\over n^3}$ is absolutely convergent right?

$f_n(x)={x^2+n^2\over n^3}$ is uniformly convergent by Dinis Theorem as they are monotone and continuos on compact set.

Comment: What is the asymptotic behaviour of $\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}$ for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: it goes to 0000000000000

Comment: But _how fast_?

Comment: :-o :-o :-o is there any way to calculate the speed?

Comment: @miosaki Well, eventually $n$ is MUCH larger than $x$... when this happens, the numerator doesn't differ from $n^2$ in a meaningful way.  So, its asymptotic rate of growth is like...

Comment: Let $x = 0$, then you series does not converge absolutely (_why?_).

Comment: bcoz $\sum {1\over n}$ is not convergent

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I do not understand :(

Comment: If $x$ is much smaller than $n$ (in, say, absolute value), then $\frac{x^2+n^2}{n^3}\approx\frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @miosaki -- it is true that $\sum 1/n$ is not convergent so without the -1 terms what can you conclude?

Comment: I can conclude that this is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: is it uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but since it has been [raised again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362298/in-the-interval-1-1-the-series-%E2%88%91-1n-1-x2n2-n3-is), I'll wrap up the comments into an answer.

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n {x^2+n^2\over n^3}$.

Does $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left|(-1)^n {x^2+n^2\over n^3}\right|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} {x^2+n^2\over n^3}$ converge for every $x\in [-1,1]$?  If the answer to this question [is yes, then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_series) $f(x;n)$ *converges absolutely* on $x\in [-1,1]$.

Now consider $g(0)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$.  [Does it converge?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))  If $g(0)$ does not converge, that means $f$ does not absolutely converge on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (hover to view):

> Since $g(0)$ diverges, $f$ does not converge absolutely on any interval including $0$, e.g. $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Comment on uniform convergence: $\sum (-1)^n {x^2+n^2\over n^3}$ indeed uniformly converges to $-\ln 2 - \frac{3\zeta(3)}{4}x^2$.